# PDO not showing in phpinfo() with custom php.ini file

Tags: php5, pdo, php.ini

I have a custom php.ini file which sets my session.save_path=./

With this file in place, my phpinfo() does not show PDO or PDO mysql being enabled. If I rename the php.ini file, the phpinfo() does show these as being enabled. How can I ensure they are enabled with my custom php.ini file?

Answer (score 1):

Your custom php.ini file is almost certainly missing the PDO module. Search for `extension=php_pdo.dll` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

The default php.ini on many linux distributions has a directive like `include /etc/php.d/*.ini`

If you want to add your own server-wide settings, add a new file with a name like `zlocal.ini` to that directory. Your file will be loaded last, so you can override anything you need to without losing the built in configuration or the ability to install modules using the package system.